# Handle Push Notification like normal push notification in-app

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have push notifications setup in my app.  My question is not "how to handle push notifications while in app" my question is how to make my push notification act like a normal push notification (a little rotating view comes in and I can tap on it) but while in my app.  An example of this is in the Messages app, from Apple, if I am messaging someone and someone else sends me a text, I get a rotating notification.  Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time on this. New push banner is coming up and it's far more easier to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what you are trying to ask.

But if you are already running your app and you receive any Push Notification, it all on you how you want to handle that in below function of your AppDelegate class.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        //Show alert message or whatever you want to do when you get any notification.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Hinata Hyuga.  Sorry my question doesn't make sense.  I am actually wanting to show the regular notification, with the rotating view, but while in my own app.  So I send a notification from my app, and have my the app receive it's own notification and display the default notification UI, instead of displaying an alert view or a custom popup.  I could replicate the rotating notification, like Desdenova sort of suggested.  I guess that's the only way.  I'll probably just stick with an AlertView for now, until iOS 7 becomes public with the easier-to-replicate push banner.